# When i signup, I want to be redirected to the article/new page but its redirecting to categories/index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

What I want is if a user signin, he gets redirected to the page so that he can create a new article. But now, he is redirected to the page where all categories are.

Here is the routes.rb

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'categories#index'
  resources :articles do
    member do
        resources :comments, only: :create
    end
  end
  resources :categories
  devise_for :users 
  get 'auth/login'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

here is the categories index page.
**CATEGORIES/INDEX**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Categories</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Published</th>
      <% if(current_user.admin?) %>
        <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
      <% else %>
        <th>Actions</th>
      <% end%>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.title %></td>
        <td><%= category.body %></td>
        <td><%= category.published%></td>
        <% if(current_user.admin?) %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', category, class: 'btn btn-default' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category), class: 'btn btn-primary' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %></td>
         <% else %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', category, class: 'btn btn-default' %></td>
         <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= paginate @categories %>

<br>
<%if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the root as 'categories#index' in your routes.rb file.  If you want to root to article/new then you have to root it to 'article#new'.

If you are using devise as authentication then you have to write in routes.rb as :-

```
   devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root to: "article#new", as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

Comment: @Debashish Thanks for the help but now i am getting the error like-- NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new undefined method `user_session_path' for #<Module:0x74d0798> Showing error in this particular line -------<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>